# What is better/quicker less memory consuming between GCHandle and unsafe

Tags: c#, unsafe

I have this code:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    IntPtr pointer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
}
finally
{
    if (handle.IsAllocated)
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

and then there is this:

```
unsafe
{
  fixed (int* pArray = array)
  {
    IntPtr intPtr = new IntPtr((void *) pArray);
  }
}
```

What is quicker and less memory consuming? What is the advisory method to use please?

ADDITIONAL:

I am calling an OpenCV DLL from C#...

```
  public  byte[] ToJpegData(int qua)
  {
      byte[] data = null;
      int[] p = new int[3];
      p[0] = 1;
      p[1] = qua;// desired_quality_value;
      p[2] = 0;

      GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(p, GCHandleType.Pinned);
      try
      {
          IntPtr quality = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();


          //IntPtr quality = new IntPtr(p);
          IntPtr mat = CvInvoke.cvEncodeImage(".jpg", Ptr, quality);// IntPtr.Zero);


          MCvMat cvMat = (MCvMat)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mat, typeof(MCvMat));
          data = new byte[cvMat.rows * cvMat.cols];
          Marshal.Copy(cvMat.data, data, 0, data.Length);
          CvInvoke.cvReleaseMat(ref mat);


      }
      finally
      {
          if (handle.IsAllocated)
          {
              handle.Free();
          }
      }

      return data;
  }
```

Comment: The code does nothing anyway. You're pinning an object for no apparent reason. Besides, __profile it__.

Comment: Hi, there is actually more code that DOES do something with the pinned object. My question was related to performance and preferred method which is why I did not include it.

Comment: @closer - perhaps you can be more specific WHY it does not conform rather than you got out of bed the wrong way?

Comment: Well, since there is a method call using `GCAlloc.Handle`.. versus a local variable being marked as `pinned` in the IL.. the `GCAlloc` call is _probably_ slower.. by slower, I mean barely measurable.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Hi, thanks for the extra info :).  I have added the rest of the code to show what I am trying to do.  The nature of the app is that I am compressing jpegs (about 10 per second - hopefully)... So that is why I am asking about the preferred methid

Comment: @downvoter... what is it you find unclear? It seems a simple enough question.

Comment: One important reason to prefer GCHandle is that it doesn't require unsafe blocks and /unsafe compilation flag. Regarding performance - just make profiling, I guess that the difference is not significant.

Comment: One more thing: you can use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` for `p` array and work without pinning. Allocate and fill it once, since it always contains the same information.

Comment: @AlexFarber many thanks for both your comments